# Apache Port forwarding 80 to 8080 and accessing applications hosted both in Apache (80), i.e phpMyadmin and Tomcat (8080)

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I want to access an application 'myapp' hosted in tomcat server(8080) currently can be accessed by http://example.com:8080/myapp in http://example.com/myapp (apache server, port 80). What should I do for that? If I use port forwarding 80 to 8080 will I be able to access phpMyadmin, or any other applications running in port 80? Which method I should follow to accomplish the task?

I am using Ubuntu server 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mod_proxy. Load module...
Second define in your virtual host:

```
    ProxyPass        /myapp         http://example.com:8080/myapp
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp         http://example.com:8080/myapp
```

But this will work when your tomcat apps has only relative links.

Comment: Can you elaborate it a bit? And what did you mean by relative links?

Comment: Sometimes links in apps are hardcoded. Relative link ../page2/index.html will work, absolute - server:8080/page3/index.html - will not. Same problem you get when you forward port.

Comment: I have absolute links in my application. Then how can I make this thing work?

Comment: In global apache.conf load  module mod_proxy, then in virtual server write proxy directives like in answer.

Comment: Maybe reconfigure tomcat? As I can remember there is conf directive with server name.I can help, but in monday...

Comment: Check http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/proxy-howto.html#Apache_2.0_Proxy_Support "Configure appropriate Engine, Host, and Context elements for the virtual hosts and web applications accessible via proxying". I haven't direct recipe, but I remember that works :)