# After Redirecting tomcat to open in apache port 80 unable to access phpmyadmn

Tags: apache, tomcat, phpmyadmin, centos7

I am working on centos for the 1st time . I have installed tomcat  which opens on port 8080 and Apache on port 80. I have redirect tomcat to port 80 by using `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/`

But the problem is I am not able to access phpmyadmin, which gives me 404 error, I tried the following links

[Link 1](http://thelinuxfaq.com/119-how-do-you-redirect-tomcat-web-application-behind-a-aache)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357772/apache-port-forwarding-80-to-8080-and-accessing-applications-hosted-both-in-apac)

[Link 3](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/~steve.swinsburg/Fronting+Tomcat+with+Apache+via+mod_proxy_ajp)

Please help me so that I could access tomcat on port 80 and I could also use phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to proxy *everything* to Tomcat... only certain web applications. Try this instead:

```
ProxyPass        /myapp1/ http://localhost:8080/myapp1/
ProxyPassReverse /myapp1/ http://localhost:8080/myapp1/

ProxyPass        /myapp2/ http://localhost:8080/myapp2/
ProxyPassReverse /myapp2/ http://localhost:8080/myapp2/
```

Now you can still access all your other resources form httpd.

Comment: Thanks @christopher. I edited a bit and it worked I used the following command  , ProxyPass  /phpmyadmin !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

ProxyPass /application/ http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /application/ http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Do you *really* need to proxy `/` over to Tomcat? If so, you won't need to also proxy `/application/` because it will already do that given the mapping for `/`.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution also given in there 1st link. You can access phpmyadmin by port 80 (apache).